# How to configure fallbacks in envoyproxy?

Tags: configuration, envoyproxy

I am trying to configure envoy as load balancer, currently stuck with fallbacks. In my playground cluster I have 3 backend servers and envoy as front proxy. I am generating some traffic on envoy using siege and watching the responses. While doing this I stop one of the backends.

**What do I want:** Envoy should resend failed requests from stopped backend to healthy one, so I will not get any 5xx responses

**What do I get:** When stopping backend I get some 503 responses, and then everything becomes normal again

What am I doing wrong? I think, `fallback_policy` should provide this functionality, but it doesn't work.

Here is my config file:

````
node:
  id: LoadBalancer_01
  cluster: HighloadCluster
admin:
  access_log_path: /var/log/envoy/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: http_listener
      address:
        socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 80 }
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                codec_type: AUTO
                route_config:
                  name: request_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service
                      domains: ["*"]
                      require_tls: NONE
                      routes:
                        - match: { prefix: "/" }
                          route:
                            cluster: backend_service
                            timeout: 1.5s
                          retry_policy:
                            retry_on: 5xx
                            num_retries: 3
                            per_try_timeout: 3s
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.router
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.router.v2.Router
                      name: envoy.file_access_log
                      typed_config:
                        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.accesslog.v2.FileAccessLog
                        path: /var/log/envoy/access.log
  clusters:
    - name: backend_service
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: STATIC
      lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
      lb_subset_config:
        fallback_policy: ANY_ENDPOINT
      outlier_detection:
        consecutive_5xx: 1
        interval: 10s
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: backend_service
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: 1.1.1.1
                      port_value: 10000
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: 2.2.2.2
                      port_value: 10000
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: 3.3.3.3
                      port_value: 10000
      health_checks:
          - http_health_check:
              path: /api/liveness-probe
            timeout: 1s
            interval: 30s
            unhealthy_interval: 10s
            unhealthy_threshold: 2
            healthy_threshold: 1
            always_log_health_check_failures: true
            event_log_path: /var/log/envoy/health_check.log```
````

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

You can use a [circuit breaker](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.21.1/api-v3/config/cluster/v3/circuit_breaker.proto) (see config example below), alongside with your `retry_policy` and `outlier_detection`.

### Explanation

#### Context

I have successfully reproduced your issue with your config (except the `health_checks` part, because I found that it was not useful to reproduce your problem).

I have run envoy and my backend (2 apps load-balanced), generated some traffic with [`hey`](https://github.com/rakyll/hey) (50 threads making requests concurrently during 10 seconds):

```
hey -c 50 -z 10s http://envoy:8080
```

And I have stopped one backend app around 5s after the command started.

#### Result

When diving into envoy admin `/stats` endpoint, I noticed interesting stuff:

```
cluster.backend_service.upstream_rq_200: 17899
cluster.backend_service.upstream_rq_503: 28

cluster.backend_service.upstream_rq_retry_overflow: 28
cluster.backend_service.upstream_rq_retry_success: 3
cluster.backend_service.upstream_rq_total: 17930
```

There were indeed 28 `503` responses when I stopped one backend app. But retry worked somehow: 3 retries were successful (`upstream_rq_retry_success`), but 28 other retries failed (`upstream_rq_retry_overflow`), resulting to `503` errors. Why ?

From the [cluster stats docs](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.21.1/configuration/upstream/cluster_manager/cluster_stats):

> `upstream_rq_retry_overflow` : Total requests not retried due to circuit breaking or exceeding the retry budget

#### Fix

To solve this, we can add a circuit breaker in the cluster (I have been generous with `max_requests`, `max_pending_requests` and `max_retries` parameters for the example). The interesting part is `retry_budget.budget_percent` value:

```yaml
  clusters:
  - name: backend_service
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: STRICT_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    outlier_detection:
      consecutive_5xx: 1
      interval: 10s
    circuit_breakers:
      thresholds:
      - priority: "DEFAULT"
        max_requests: 0xffffffff
        max_pending_requests: 0xffffffff
        max_retries: 0xffffffff
        retry_budget:
          budget_percent:
            value: 100.0
```

From the [`retry_budget` docs](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.21.1/api-v3/config/cluster/v3/circuit_breaker.proto#config-cluster-v3-circuitbreakers-thresholds-retrybudget):

> **budget_percent**: Specifies the limit on concurrent retries as a percentage of the sum of active requests and active pending requests. For example, if there are 100 active requests and the budget_percent is set to 25, there may be 25 active retries.
>
> This parameter is optional. Defaults to 20%.

I set it to 100.0 to allow 100% of active retries.

When running the example again with this new config, there is no more `upstream_rq_retry_overflow`, so no more `503` errors:

```
cluster.backend_service.upstream_rq_200: 17051

cluster.backend_service.upstream_rq_retry_overflow: 0
cluster.backend_service.upstream_rq_retry_success: 5
cluster.backend_service.upstream_rq_total: 17056
```

Note that if you experience `upstream_rq_retry_limit_exceeded`, you can try to set and increase `retry_budget.min_retry_concurrency` (default when not set is 3):

```yaml
        retry_budget:
          budget_percent:
            value: 100.0
          min_retry_concurrency: 10
```